# What type of RAID/NAS configuration is this?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, debian, raid, nas

I'm trying to install Debian stable on a server with fedora 18 server.
According to fdisk it has two 2TB RAID HDDs and one standar configured hdd of 60GB configured with device-mapper.
I'm finding hard to understand how the server was partitioned/configured (never used NAS before). Mainly I want to preserve the NAS configuration/local storage and format "/" root partition. It looks like the 60GB hdd is the one containing the OS and NAS is only mirrored in /home location. I just want to install debian instead of fedora. How/where?

```
[root@stupul raid1]# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 1,8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/sdb: 58,7 GiB, 63023063040 bytes, 123091920 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D81B7E4E-4C73-4BCE-81CE-E25A16CD701C
Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1     2048    411647    409600  200M EFI System
/dev/sdb2   411648   1435647   1024000  500M Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3  1435648 123090943 121655296   58G Linux LVM
Disk /dev/sdc: 1,8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-swap: 5,9 GiB, 6304038912 bytes, 12312576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-root: 48,8 GiB, 52428800000 bytes, 102400000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/md126: 1,8 TiB, 2000395698176 bytes, 3907022848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-home: 3,3 GiB, 3552575488 bytes, 6938624 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes



mdadm --examine /dev/sda
/dev/sda:
Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
Version : 1.1.00
Orig Family : 2d0c0838
Family : 2d0c0838
Generation : 00002ad3
Attributes : All supported
UUID : f297b619:b23e7f94:6de61051:de1206fa
Checksum : ee7d1b12 correct
MPB Sectors : 1
Disks : 2
RAID Devices : 1
Disk00 Serial : WD-WCC4MJHPCJC5
State : active
Id : 00000000
Usable Size : 3907023112 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
[RAID_NAS]:
UUID : dd6bace9:8de874e8:8bab02f5:0e8e07d8
RAID Level : 1
Members : 2
Slots : [UU]
Failed disk : none
This Slot : 0
Array Size : 3907022848 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
Per Dev Size : 3907023112 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
Sector Offset : 0
Num Stripes : 15261808
Chunk Size : 64 KiB
Reserved : 0
Migrate State : idle
Map State : normal
Dirty State : clean
Disk01 Serial : WD-WCC4MA4VUR0J
State : active
Id : 00000003
Usable Size : 3907023112 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)



[root@stupul raid1]# mdadm --examine /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc:
Magic : Intel Raid ISM Cfg Sig.
Version : 1.1.00
Orig Family : 2d0c0838
Family : 2d0c0838
Generation : 00002ad3
Attributes : All supported
UUID : f297b619:b23e7f94:6de61051:de1206fa
Checksum : ee7d1b12 correct
MPB Sectors : 1
Disks : 2
RAID Devices : 1
Disk01 Serial : WD-WCC4MA4VUR0J
State : active
Id : 00000003
Usable Size : 3907023112 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
[RAID_NAS]:
UUID : dd6bace9:8de874e8:8bab02f5:0e8e07d8
RAID Level : 1
Members : 2
Slots : [UU]
Failed disk : none
This Slot : 1
Array Size : 3907022848 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
Per Dev Size : 3907023112 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)
Sector Offset : 0
Num Stripes : 15261808
Chunk Size : 64 KiB
Reserved : 0
Migrate State : idle
Map State : normal
Dirty State : clean
Disk00 Serial : WD-WCC4MJHPCJC5
State : active
Id : 00000000
Usable Size : 3907023112 (1863.01 GiB 2000.40 GB)


ls /home
bin                                  nas
code                                 nginx.conf.old
documents                            plexmediaserver-0.9.16.3.1840-cece46d.x86_64.rpm
gitlab-ce-8.3.7-ce.0.el7.x86_64.rpm  server
hubot



mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=3999856k,nr_inodes=999964,mode=755)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
bpf on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/mapper/fedora-root on / type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=34,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=16257)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
systemd-1 on /media/nas type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=48,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=1874)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sdb2 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdb1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=winnt,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/mapper/fedora-home on /home type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
systemd-1 on /home/abucur/nas type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=61,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=26389)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=803052k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1001)
/dev/md126 on /media/nas type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota,x-systemd.automount)
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=803052k,mode=700)
/dev/md126 on /home/abucur/nas type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota,x-systemd.automount)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing type tracefs (rw,relatime)
```

EDITED:

```
[root@stupul ~]# pvdisplay
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sdb3
VG Name               fedora
PV Size               <58,01 GiB / not usable 2,00 MiB
Allocatable           yes (but full)
PE Size               4,00 MiB
Total PE              14850
Free PE               0
Allocated PE          14850
PV UUID               TXYgMl-9LcU-z3Dl-nPQE-Qc7p-ts0c-ELuWOT



[root@stupul ~]# vgdisplay
--- Volume group ---
VG Name               fedora
System ID             
Format                lvm2
Metadata Areas        1
Metadata Sequence No  7
VG Access             read/write
VG Status             resizable
MAX LV                0
Cur LV                3
Open LV               3
Max PV                0
Cur PV                1
Act PV                1
VG Size               <58,01 GiB
PE Size               4,00 MiB
Total PE              14850
Alloc PE / Size       14850 / <58,01 GiB
Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
VG UUID               eja5ya-mrB6-ukFI-TIhb-MMWF-ifSG-YbnJvs



[root@stupul ~]# lvdisplay
--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/fedora/swap
LV Name                swap
VG Name                fedora
LV UUID                kUDQUz-PhJd-BgsT-JvfR-eH1v-6QEl-ja9Z54
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time stupul, 2015-07-28 22:58:14 +0300
LV Status              available
# open                 2
LV Size                5,87 GiB
Current LE             1503
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           253:0
--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/fedora/root
LV Name                root
VG Name                fedora
LV UUID                JAEy6h-dcxt-6Ung-hri9-tfrd-kgkZ-KV2faF
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time stupul, 2015-07-28 22:58:17 +0300
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                <48,83 GiB
Current LE             12500
Segments               2
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           253:1
--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/fedora/home
LV Name                home
VG Name                fedora
LV UUID                yoWz1f-igvl-y3RE-W0KU-FZWD-1aWO-r59DWB
LV Write Access        read/write
LV Creation host, time stupul, 2015-08-05 00:32:34 +0300
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                <3,31 GiB
Current LE             847
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           253:2
```

Comment: "_NAS_" is a concept (Network Attached Storage) - from the local machine it's just storage..."_mirrored in /home_" it looks like you mean "_mounted on /home_", which could be considered a very different thing.

Comment: This machine appears to be configured with [LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)), and as such, you'll need to use the relevant utilities to see how the storage has been structured. Please run `pvdisplay`, `vgdisplay` and `lvdisplay`, and edit your question with the output. It would be worth reading up before you go much further (certainly before trying a reinstall while preserving the data) so that you understand the concepts involved.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Did you include the full output of `pvdisplay`? I'm not sure what's going on here, but at a guess you might have two groups, both named `fedora`?? Could you update the question with the output of `pvdisplay --all` instead?...